# Why Rails 3 does not work with jQuery 1.4.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I downloaded `rails.js` [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src) and included it in `views/layouts/application.html.erb` along with jQuery:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.4.min.js', 'rails.js' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

However, on page load I got the following error in browser's console (I use the latest Firefox):

```
Error: syntax error
Source File: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/rails.js?1292414064
Line: 6
Source Code:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *highly* recommend the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem. once you have it installed, a simple `rails g jquery:install` and everything is taken care of for you properly.

Comment: Which files should I download there ? And where to put them ?

Comment: @Misha: I believe gem install jquery-rails will do it for you. Then, as Matt says, run rails g jquery:install - that should download the jQuery files and install the files necessary to make it work within Rails.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with the `rails.js` file. I didn't download it properly (downloaded some HTML file instead, which is shown in the error message...). Thanks again!